# Find the index number of given value from the list using TCL

Tags: list, indexing, tcl

Need to find the index number of given value from list. I have a value from the list ,But i need to find the index number of of the value.

```
set i 0.0001646481396164745
set X [list 1.215647671415354e-7 1.1284486163276597e-6 4.538622670224868e-5 4.4706815970130265e-5 8.492852430208586e-6 6.077577836549608e-6 3.1041158763400745e-6 0.00015045881445985287 4.1016753016265284e-7 1.165599314845167e-6 1.8736355968940188e-6 2.9444883693940938e-5 2.5420340534765273e-5 2.0819682049477706e-6 9.529731869406532e-6 8.549810104341304e-7 1.558014082547743e-5 8.079621693468653e-6 4.868444739258848e-5 0.0001646481396164745]
```

have to **find** **the index value of i from list X using TCL**.

Comment: While straight up floating point equality can be tricky, start with http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsearch.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be easily solved with **[lsearch](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsearch.htm)**:

```
set c [lsearch $X $i]
```

Comment: If you know that the value is definitely there (e.g., if it was previously taken from the same source that generated that list) then that's the right approach. However, you _really_ need to be careful with floating point values and equality because of the detailed behaviours of least significant bits of floats (strictly double precision floats in Tcl's case). Tcl's a _bit_ better than average languages as it has exact minimal float→string conversion, but you can still be surprised.

Comment: I'd use the `-real` option here too, but that's what I hoping you'd come with on your own from my earlier comment. Good work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a floating point value in a list where you only know the *approximate* value, you can't use `lsearch`. Instead you have to do it yourself:

```
proc findApprox {theList theValue {epsilon 1e-9}} {
    set idx 0
    foreach x $theList {
        # Found if the difference between the list item and the target is less than epsilon
        if {abs($theValue - $x) < $epsilon} {
            return $idx
        }
        incr idx
    }
    return -1
    # Or [error "not found"] if you prefer
}

set x [findApprox $X $i]
```

Note the `epsilon` optional argument. That's because how close you have to get depends on knowledge of the domain of the input data; it's not something that it is easy for a basic algorithm to determine for you.